# Microsoft Graph Powershell Module

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When using the Graph powershell module I get a "get-mgeducationuser : Required claim values are not provided" permissions error when I try to run "get-mgeducationuser" what permissions are required for this?

I believe all i need is  to connect with EduRoster.Read permissions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to connect to your tenant and provide proper permissions.
Please follow the [document](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell#run-generated-modules) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation. I have created an application and I am connecting to it using powershell. But now when I run get-mgeducationclassassignment -classid xxx I get an unknown error. I have applied EduAdministration.Read.All, EduAssignments.Read.All and EduRoster.Read.All permissions to the application so I believe I should have permissions to see all of the class assignments.

Comment: Yes and you need to pass permission in connect-graph cmdlet